# Thumbnails are stretching to match the width (100%) on fancybox

Tags: php, html, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

I've looked through the documentation to see if there was a property to change thumbnail size but couldn't see any. This is what my site looks like currently: [image: my website homepage] . I am not using separate images for thumbnails and would prefer not to. This is the code that I have.

```
<?php 
// Include database configuration file  
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
// Retrieve images from the database 
$query = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY uploaded_date DESC"); 
    if(!$query) {
        trigger_error("Invalid query: " . $DB->error);
    }
if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $imageURL = '../phpgallery/'.$row["path"]; 
?>
    <a href="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $row["title"]; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" width="300"/>
</a>
<?php } 
} ?>
```

Other aspects of fancybox works, such as enlarging photos and clicking left and right. (Scrolling through images and preventing copying and pasting do not work).

The two images that have been stretched are vertical images.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Pipetus How do I stop the images stretching?

Answer (score 0):

**PHP:**

`getimagesize ( string $filename [, array &$imageinfo ] ) : array`

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.getimagesize.php

or

**CSS:**

`background-size: auto|length|cover|contain|initial|inherit;`

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I want to stop the images stretching in fancy box @ChrisG
CSS won't change the properties of fancybox.

Comment: The question is what exactly do you need. I manage it with CSS .. if you need the size of the images you use `getimagesize` and print it in the code.

Comment: There's also a `width` attribute for the image. That's usually handled by other means, and I think that's what @ChrisG is suggesting when he asks "what do you need to do", in the sense of "where do you need to define the image sizes"

Comment: The `width` he can serve using `getimagesize` to get the images dimension.. its quite simple.